# JScrollPane and responsive GUI with gridbaglayout

Tags: swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, responsive

Hi everyone I trying to create a chat session GUI. I managed to position all the components in the correct order. The only problem is that the Frame is not responding, whenever I try to resize the window the component stays with the same dimension, also when I type in text in the JtextArea, they border enlarges taking over any other component in the frame. I have tried using JScrollPane or setting the maximum dimension but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me. This is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

public class ClientGUI extends JPanel {

    public ClientGUI() {
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 500;
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Peron"));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JTextArea chat, list;
        JTextField wm;
        JButton sm, sf, pm, lo;
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("FRAME");
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setSize(200, 200);
        fr.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1400, 1000));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        fr.add(panel);

        gbc.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
        chat = new JTextArea("Welcome to the chat room");
        // chat.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(chat); // place the JTextArea in a
                                                    // scroll pane
        panel.add(scroll);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc.gridheight = 7;
        // gbc.gridwidth = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.ipady = 400;
        gbc.ipadx = 200;
        panel.add(chat, gbc);

        wm = new JTextField("Insert message", 10);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        gbc.ipady = 150;
        gbc.ipadx = 300;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 10;
        panel.add(wm, gbc);

        list = new JTextArea("User online");

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.ipady = 400;
        gbc.ipadx = 300;
        panel.add(list, gbc);

        sm = new JButton("Send");
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 10;
        gbc.ipady = 20;
        gbc.ipadx = 200;
        panel.add(sm, gbc);

        pm = new JButton("Private message");
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 10;
        gbc.ipady = 20;
        gbc.ipadx = 20;
        panel.add(pm, gbc);

        lo = new JButton("LOGOUT");
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.ipady = 20;
        panel.add(lo, gbc);

        sf = new JButton("Send File");
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 10;
        gbc.ipady = 20;
        gbc.ipadx = 20;
        panel.add(sf, gbc);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem with the text area is where you put `panel.add(scroll)`. Delete this line. Also, you should be adding the scroll pane and not the text area to the panel. Change `panel.add(chat,gbc)` to `panel.add(scroll,gbc)`

Comment: Do you know how to get the component to respond from the user resizing the window?

Comment: @Werokk can you clarify what you mean? I seemed to noticed the frame acting odd as well. I remove the two lines of `fr.setMinimumSize()` and `fr.setSize()` and added `fr.pack()` at the end of the code. 

I would highly suggest restructuring the code to separate the panel and frame configuration for easier troubleshooting.

Comment: @Werokk, `Thank you so much, it worked! ` - then don't forge to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I had to fr.setMinimumSize(); because in that dimension the components are aligned correctly, but if I make the window smaller I can see only some of the components because the components don't change dimension

Comment: @Werokk You may want to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198953/how-to-dynamically-control-auto-resize-components-in-java-swing)