# How to make full screen Java app.?

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen, layout-manager

I want to make a Java app. with full screen which would run correctly on all screen resolution.

I tried `Toolkit` in my `JFrame` it made my frame full screen but some its components (e.g. `JButton`, `JTextField`) were not shown when I run it on 800 x 600 screen size, but properly shown in 1600 x 900 screen size.

How to make full screen Java app. with robust component layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically control auto-resize components in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198953/how-to-dynamically-control-auto-resize-components-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you used 'null' for your JFrame

```
setLayout(null).
```

Please use your required [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for the JFrame

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
JFrame jf = new JFrame();
jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
jf.setUndecorated(true);
jf.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thnks but my JFrame is working correctly according to screen resolution but not its component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);**

Answer (score 0):

`this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`
you can try the above one it will resize the whole java app window to the available desktop resolution.